# Experience Editor is very slow to load the Ribbon.aspx, logs show WARN Cannot resolve resource item

Tags: experience-editor

After a Sitecore upgrade, the EE is very slow to load the Ribbon.aspx page.
The logs are showing `WARN  Cannot resolve  resource item` but there is no other indication as to what the issue is.

I realise this is somewhat an upgrade specific issue but the log message indicates it is somewhat platform related and therefore is possibly an issue that multiple people might get.

Answer (score 2):

The steps I took to resolve:

- ILSpy find the source of the error - it is coming from `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Web.ResourceCollector.SessionResourceCollector` looking for EE js files - noted a way to disable this with `WebEdit.EnableJSBundling false` - tested that which made it fast but the EE is broken with JS errors
- `Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.Ribbon.RibbonComponentControlBase` is the one adding a `PageCodeScriptFileName`. To me this means there is an ribbon component that is not correctly configured. Considering that this issue is recent , might be a core DB upgrade issue or maybe an issue with a custom module.
- I notice we have 2 custom modules - Global Link and KeyStone on the ribbon. Likely one of these is not configured right.
- Try and click on Global Link and KeyStone ribbons icons - these are triggering a 404 on js files!
- After checking requirements, we don't actually need these modules anymore.
- Deleted `core:/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Global Link` and
  `core:/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Ribbons/WebEdit/Keystone` - Issue resolved!

I hope this helps others if they have a similar issue.